# How to preload a java method before rendering a view

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a spring MVC application based on spring and JSP to visualize some date on web pages. My controller originally looks like this.

```
public class MyController {
    public ModelAndView visualizeData() {
        List myList = MyClass.getMyList();
        return new ModelAndView("myurl", "myList", myList);
    }
}
```

Now I want to split this `ModelAndView` method, because the `MyClass.getMyList()` is slow if it gets executed at the time the user clicks `/myurl`. I want it to be executed silently before a user clicks `/myurl`, fetch `myList` and store in client's cache before the data gets rendered so that the user won't feel the delay for displaying `myList`. How can I do that?

Comment: How do we know the user is going to click `/myUrl`?

Comment: There are only two buttons there, one is download data, another one is visualize data. Most likely the users will want to visualize the data at first. But this is not a concern in my question anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use AJAX here. Have an action that simply renders the page (i.e., when they hit `/myurl`, and then use an `onload` event along with AJAX to hit a separate action (perhaps `/myurl/getList`) that loads the list and then returns it as JSON.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion. Still have a question, how can I have data preloaded before the user click '/myurl' to render the page if I do it as you suggested here?